# Gmail POP emails disappear after a while

Tags: email, gmail, pop3

After a period of a few days, I've noticed that Gmail seems to just get rid of emails previously in my POP account inbox. They aren't in the trash, and I never deleted them or removed them in any way. They just vanish. The *Load More button* doesn't seem to do anything either.

Where do they go? How can I prevent this?